# podman container is in ephemeral state so that with server restart it won't start up automatically

Tags: podman

I have `podman image` and `container` for `mysql` latest built and start/run in `rhel8` server as AWS ec2 instance.

I noticed whenever I restart the server, image is still found however container is not started up automatically.

```
podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE       COMMAND     CREATED     STATUS      PORTS       NAMES
```

I believe container is in `/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay-containers`.

I read in somewhere container is in ephemeral state and I need to find a way to store container in non-transient state.  So far my research didn't turn up much. If I understood the problem correctly, what procedure I have to run so that restart of the server would keep the container in `running` state?

Update:

I am looking for a clue from `/etc/containers/storage.conf` file. However I am not sure I am in the right place start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Docker, there is no Podman daemon to automatically start your containers when your system starts.

If you want a container to start automatically, you need to configure that yourself -- e.g., by creating an appropriate systemd unit (possibly via `podman generate systemd`), or by using a tool such as [quadlet](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/quadlet-podman).

Comment: Thank you @larsks! I found plenty of articles on ```podman generate systemd```.  Will read upon them then will try the given method.

Comment: I am able to start/stop podman container via ```systemctl --user start/stop container-mysql.service``` after taking reco from @larsks.

Comment: Forgot to mention, container is also up/running after the server reboot after taking his reco.